# C# MemoryMappedFile - Different Processes for Read & Write

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files, file-security

I have some problems with MemoryMappedFiles in C#.
They are working perfect when I am using only 1 process, but as soon as I try to access the mmf-file from different processes I get errors that this is permitted.

I have a data-logger, which writes incoming data into the mmf file:

```
private void WriteRawToFile(.....)
    {
        MemoryMappedFileSecurity security = new MemoryMappedFileSecurity();
        security.AddAccessRule(new AccessRule<MemoryMappedFileRights>(("Everyone"), MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));

        using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(new FileStream(@"data.mmf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate), "mmf", Int32.MaxValue / 100, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWriteExecute, security, HandleInheritability.Inheritable, false))
        {
            using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor view = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(size*rawId, size, MemoryMappedFileAccess.CopyOnWrite))
            {
                    view.WriteArray(....);
            }
        }
    }
```

Other threads (and the mainthread) read from this file (from another class):

```
private float[] ReadRawFromFile(....)
        {
            MemoryMappedFileSecurity security = new MemoryMappedFileSecurity();
            security.AddAccessRule(new AccessRule<MemoryMappedFileRights>(("Everyone"), MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
            using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(new FileStream(@"data.mmf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate), "mmf", Int32.MaxValue / 100, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWriteExecute, security, HandleInheritability.Inheritable, false))
            {
                using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor view = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(size*rawId, size, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read))
                {
                    view.ReadArray(....);
                }
            }
            return res;
        }
```

With this code I get an exception while reading:

```
Some or all identity references could not be translated.
```

Initally I tried it without the MemoryMappedFileSecurity:

```
using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile("data.mmf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate , "mmf", Int32.MaxValue / 100, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWriteExecute))
using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile("data.mmf", FileMode.Open, "mmf", Int32.MaxValue / 100, MemoryMappedFileAccess.Read))
```

but then I got another Exception:

```
The process cannot access the file 'data.mmf' because it is being used by another process.
```

What do I do wrong, I couldn't find a solution so far.

Comment: This message is extremely common. Did you search for it?

Comment: I found half a dozen problems, which were nearly like mine, but neither realy helped me.

Comment: You might want to sidestep this file access issue by using a strictly memory-based mmf (use `CreateNew` instead of `CreateFromFile`).

Comment: Yes, that was the main solution the internet provided, but I have a huge amount of data (like 100GB-1TB), so I need to save it on the harddrive (and access it there at any point in time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message has nothing to do with security. It's about file sharing access to the same file.

The `CreateFromFile` overload that you used always uses `FileShare.None` according to reflector. That does not seem useful. [Use a better overload.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267557(v=vs.110).aspx) Here, you can create the `FileStream` yourself and use the proper sharing mode.

Comment: I changed the Filestreams to `new FileStream(@"data.mmf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite)`, but now I get another exception:  Access to the path is denied.

Comment: Post the full exception ToString. And delete your security code.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Core.dll

Additional information: Access to the path is denied.

Comment: That means file security does not allow access. Fix that. Probably a remnant of a previous experiment of yours. Maybe you should try googling more for error messages. This is not hard to figure out.

Comment: I already searched the internet for that and found solutions like stackoverflow.com/questions/12358568/ but they also return the access denied exception, and for that exception I dont find a solution.

Comment: OK, what happened after trying out my suggestions from the previous comment. Use a new file name to be sure that no old security is lingering.

Comment: The problem was that I tried to manage read and write permissions.

Streams FileAccess and FileShare, also the MemoryMappedFileAccess have to be set to ReadWrite (and nothing else), even when only reading data. I dont get why, but it works now.